# change voice in react-speech-kit

Tags: reactjs

I am using useSpeechSynthesis of react-speech-kit to read the text when click button. This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';
 
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const { speak } = useSpeechSynthesis();
 
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => speak({ text: value })}>Speak</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The default voice is a man. How can I change the voice

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem of wanting to change the voice. The following method worked for me.

`const { speak, voices } = useSpeechSynthesis();`

`<button onClick={() => speak({ text: value, voice: voices[1] })}>Speak</button>`

I've found the idea from this [link](https://github.com/craig1123/react-recipes/blob/master/docs/useSpeechSynthesis.md).

Answer (score 0):

In the speak function that you are calling during the onClick event there is an other key value that you can pass beyond text and it's "voice"

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';
 
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const { speak } = useSpeechSynthesis();
 
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => speak({ text: value, voice:SpeechSynthesisVoice })}>Speak</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The speech synthesis voice is available in the voices array.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know this example in react-speech-kit, but I don't know how to pass anything in SpeechSynthesisVoice to change the voice

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem when I want to change voice from default, to a female Italian accent. The following method worked for me.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';
        
function Example() {
    const { speak, voices } = useSpeechSynthesis();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        //console.log("You will get all voices here",voices);
        const selectedVoice = voices.find(voice => voice.lang.includes('it-IT'));
        speak({ text: "Put your text here", voice: selectedVoice });
    }, [])
}
```